# Why does Go send my multicast packet only using loopback interface?

Tags: go, udp, multicast

I can not send multicast request to LAN from Go on Win10.

I have Windows 10 1909.

I am running wireshark with filter `host 239.255.255.250 or host 172.19.21.116 or port 1982` where `.116` is IP of device I am looking for.

I have [YeeLight UWP app](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/p/yeelight-uwp/9nk1nf9zs4l4?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) installed

I have this code (*removed every `if err != nil`*):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    bulbMulticastAddr := &net.UDPAddr{IP: net.IPv4(239, 255, 255, 250), Port: 1982}
    bulbSearchRequest := new(bytes.Buffer)
    _, err := bulbSearchRequest.WriteString("M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST:239.255.255.250:1982\r\nMAN:\"ssdp:discover\"\r\nST:wifi_bulb\r\n")
    conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp4", bulbMulticastAddr)
    conn.WriteTo(bulbSearchRequest.Bytes(), bulbMulticastAddr)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(6) * time.Second)
}
```

When I run `go run myapp`, in WireShark I see single UDP packet with source `127.0.0.1` and destination `239.255.255.250`

When I run Yeelight UWP app, in WireShark I see in WireShark two same packets: one using Ethernet interface and one using loopback.

And after some time OS works (few hours - different apps are running), it starts working.

When I use

```
iflist, _ := net.Interfaces() // iflist[0] is Ethernet
conn, err := net.ListenMulticastUDP("udp4", &iflist[0], bulbMulticastAddr)
conn.WriteTo(bulbSearchRequest.Bytes(), bulbMulticastAddr)
```

Everything goes right

What am I doing wrong? Each tutorial about multicast shows the way I am doing is right, but it does not work as expected. I am missing something?

Why ListenUDP() not working as expected?

`go version go1.14 windows/amd64`

Comment: Can you explain a bit what actually works and what not. E.g. this sentence is unclear:
`And after some time OS works (few hours - different apps are running), it starts working.` - what do you consider 'starts working' to be?
Also - `Everything goes right` (after the second code example) - what do you mean by 'going right'.

Comment: #1. When I reboot PC, run wireshark, and run code above ( first example ) via `go run myapp.go`, I see packet FROM source 127.0.0.1 via Loopback interface in Wireshark. No packet from Ethernet if
#2. After some time I work, play etc. I run this again and I see TWO lines in wireshark: One line same as above (Loopback interface, source 127.0.0.1), and one from my Ethernet interface and my IP (172.19.x.x).
#3. If I run second example, I see the one line same as in (2) - from my Ethernet interface and my IP (source 172.19.x.x)

I Expect that (2) is SHOULD BE behaviour. Mut maybe I am wrong?